# how to load php page after loading all the other content of page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am developing an web based video channel where I have to add mailing functionality. I have added a mail button, all the functionality is working fine, but it is taking more time to load the page. I have included `mail.php` in the `video.php` page. Whole page wait until `mail.php` is included. Hence it is taking more time.

**Note my application is developed in PHP codeigniter.**
*mail.php contain some js file,ajax call,and html form.*

Can i do something to load all the page content first then at last load mail.php in background.

here what i tried...

video.php

```
<script>jQuery("#mail_btn").click(function()jQuery("#div1").load(mail.php);});</script>
<div id="div1" class ="mail_form">
//include_once(mail.php); //it was working fine but it takes time,i want to load mail form here.
</div>
```

please help me or suggest any alternative way.
Thanks..

Comment: You should show more code.

Comment: It's impossible t tell without any code shown, but to load code from jquery does not seem to be a good way of achieving what you want. You should identify why the php code is to slow instead and make appropiate actions after that.

Comment: Just running `include_once` does usually not take time - have you tried debugging your code to see which parts are crucial for loading performance?

Comment: I tried to identify why it is slow, it is all because of external js library i have included in mail.php. To achieve my requirement i have to load those library.So what to do now. @bestprogrammerintheworld

Comment: Thanks all , It was slow due to database connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the jQuery lazy load plugin http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/. I added a snippet below but there are better examples on the plugin site.

```js
$(function() {
    $("div[data-src]").Lazy();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.lazy/1.7.1/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.lazy/1.7.1/plugins/jquery.lazy.ajax.min.js"></script>

<div data-loader="ajax" data-src="ajax.html">
  <p>Content you want to load later goes here.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: for this i have to load more library , means it will take more time to run

Comment: Yes you would need to load the jQuery plugin, but it is very lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use `Ob_start` and `ob_end_flush`
 those are function to control the page output loading and display
check the manual here 
[php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)